# How to import any module in AWS lambda which throw the Unable to import error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to scrape one website stuck with   `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'",`

- How to import any module in AWS lambda which throw the `Unable to import`  error.

Disclaimer :  I am not running on  EC2 instance

- i need to put `x.text` in the s3 bucket

code is below

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')
print(x.text)
```

Comment: i am using serverless computing only where i should write lambda handler

Comment: Any blog i should follow ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices for packaging extra python dependencies:

- Run a `pip install` and zip the contents along with your Lambda function. Upload this Zip to your Python function.
- Create a Lambda layer that you can then use with your Lambda function.

Regarding `requests` it is [no longer included](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/) in the base Lambda setup.

AWS have a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/) that explains how to include these files in your codebase.

It also includes the AWS Arns for public Labda layers containing the `requests` dependency, although it does cap the SDK at a slightly older version.

Comment: Can you share one example or blog i could follow?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/ < Read this, you can either create your own Labda layer or use the lambda layer arn specified in this post

Answer (score 0):

In order to use external packages in AWS Lambda, as stated in [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html), you should pack your dependencies along with your code and upload it all together.

Comment: I don't have any EC2 instance. This is high level flow. could you share any blog i could ollow new to AWS

Comment: You don't need EC2 for that. You have a problem with running your Lambda function in the first place, fix that and then you'll be able to eventually save the response to your S3 bucket.